# Display error message on entering a negative number

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

Display error message on entering a negative number

I am working on building a currency converter using an API. I want to display an error message when a negative amount is entered in the amount input field. Can this be handled using catch function in the promise?

Please help, Thank you

Here is the html and javascript code

HTML

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="currency.css"/>
    <script defer src="currency.js"></script>
    <title>Currency calculator</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
    <h1>Currency converter</h1>
    <p>Choose the currency and the amount</p>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="currency">
            <select id="currency-one">
                <option value="AED">AED</option>
          <option value="ARS">ARS</option>
          <option value="AUD">AUD</option>
          <option value="BGN">BGN</option>
          <option value="BRL">BRL</option>
          <option value="BSD">BSD</option>
          <option value="CAD">CAD</option>
          <option value="CHF">CHF</option>
          <option value="CLP">CLP</option>
          <option value="CNY">CNY</option>
          <option value="COP">COP</option>
          <option value="CZK">CZK</option>
          <option value="DKK">DKK</option>
          <option value="DOP">DOP</option>
          <option value="EGP">EGP</option>
          <option value="EUR">EUR</option>
          <option value="FJD">FJD</option>
          <option value="GBP">GBP</option>
          <option value="GTQ">GTQ</option>
          <option value="HKD">HKD</option>
          <option value="HRK">HRK</option>
          <option value="HUF">HUF</option>
          <option value="IDR">IDR</option>
          <option value="ILS">ILS</option>
          <option value="INR">INR</option>
          <option value="ISK">ISK</option>
          <option value="JPY">JPY</option>
          <option value="KRW">KRW</option>
          <option value="KZT">KZT</option>
          <option value="MXN">MXN</option>
          <option value="MYR">MYR</option>
          <option value="NOK">NOK</option>
          <option value="NZD">NZD</option>
          <option value="PAB">PAB</option>
          <option value="PEN">PEN</option>
          <option value="PHP">PHP</option>
          <option value="PKR">PKR</option>
          <option value="PLN">PLN</option>
          <option value="PYG">PYG</option>
          <option value="RON">RON</option>
          <option value="RUB">RUB</option>
          <option value="SAR">SAR</option>
          <option value="SEK">SEK</option>
          <option value="SGD">SGD</option>
          <option value="THB">THB</option>
          <option value="TRY">TRY</option>
          <option value="TWD">TWD</option>
          <option value="UAH">UAH</option>
          <option value="USD" selected>USD</option>
          <option value="UYU">UYU</option>
          <option value="VND">VND</option>
          <option value="ZAR">ZAR</option>
            </select>
        <input type="number" min= "0" id="amount-one" value="1">
        </div>

        <div class="swap-rate-container">
            <button class="btn">Swap</button>
            <div class="rate"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="currency">
        <select id="currency-two">
            <option value="AED">AED</option>
      <option value="ARS">ARS</option>
      <option value="AUD">AUD</option>
      <option value="BGN">BGN</option>
      <option value="BRL">BRL</option>
      <option value="BSD">BSD</option>
      <option value="CAD">CAD</option>
      <option value="CHF">CHF</option>
      <option value="CLP">CLP</option>
      <option value="CNY">CNY</option>
      <option value="COP">COP</option>
      <option value="CZK">CZK</option>
      <option value="DKK">DKK</option>
      <option value="DOP">DOP</option>
      <option value="EGP">EGP</option>
      <option value="EUR">EUR</option>
      <option value="FJD">FJD</option>
      <option value="GBP">GBP</option>
      <option value="GTQ">GTQ</option>
      <option value="HKD">HKD</option>
      <option value="HRK">HRK</option>
      <option value="HUF">HUF</option>
      <option value="IDR">IDR</option>
      <option value="ILS">ILS</option>
      <option value="INR" selected>INR</option>
      <option value="ISK">ISK</option>
      <option value="JPY">JPY</option>
      <option value="KRW">KRW</option>
      <option value="KZT">KZT</option>
      <option value="MXN">MXN</option>
      <option value="MYR">MYR</option>
      <option value="NOK">NOK</option>
      <option value="NZD">NZD</option>
      <option value="PAB">PAB</option>
      <option value="PEN">PEN</option>
      <option value="PHP">PHP</option>
      <option value="PKR">PKR</option>
      <option value="PLN">PLN</option>
      <option value="PYG">PYG</option>
      <option value="RON">RON</option>
      <option value="RUB">RUB</option>
      <option value="SAR">SAR</option>
      <option value="SEK">SEK</option>
      <option value="SGD">SGD</option>
      <option value="THB">THB</option>
      <option value="TRY">TRY</option>
      <option value="TWD">TWD</option>
      <option value="UAH">UAH</option>
      <option value="USD">USD</option>
      <option value="UYU">UYU</option>
      <option value="VND">VND</option>
      <option value="ZAR">ZAR</option>
        </select>
        <input type="number" id="amount-two">
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>

Javascript code

    const currencyOne = document.querySelector('#currency-one');
const currencyTwo = document.querySelector('#currency-two');
const amountOne = document.querySelector('#amount-one');
const amountTwo = document.querySelector('#amount-two');
const swapButton = document.querySelector('.btn');
const rateEl = document.querySelector('.rate');


//Calculate function to fetch currency rates

function calculate(){
    const currency_one = currencyOne.value;
    const currency_two = currencyTwo.value;
    fetch(`https://v6.exchangerate-api.com/v6/0a8724f8d325969fedf0f714/latest/${currency_one}`)
   .then(res => res.json())
.then(data =>{
const rate = data.conversion_rates[currency_two];
rateEl.innerHTML = `1 ${currency_one} = ${rate} ${currency_two}`;
amountTwo.value = (amountOne.value * rate).toFixed(2);
})
}

//event listener for currency element 1
currencyOne.addEventListener('change',calculate);
currencyTwo.addEventListener('change',calculate);
amountOne.addEventListener('input',calculate);
amountTwo.addEventListener('input',calculate);

swapButton.addEventListener('click',function(){
    const temp = currencyOne.value;
    currencyOne.value = currencyTwo.value;
    currencyTwo.value = temp;
    calculate();
})
calculate();
```

Comment: You should do it before calling the API.

Comment: @Barmar Thank you for the quick response, Can you please show with code snippet please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would check it as the first thing in the `calculate` function like this:

```js
function calculate() {
  const currency_one = currencyOne.value;
  const currency_two = currencyTwo.value;
  if (currency_one < 0 || currency_two < 0 ) {
    alert("currency cannot be less than 0");
  } else {
    fetch(
      `https://v6.exchangerate-api.com/v6/0a8724f8d325969fedf0f714/latest/${currency_one}`
    )
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => {
        const rate = data.conversion_rates[currency_two];
        rateEl.innerHTML = `1 ${currency_one} = ${rate} ${currency_two}`;
        amountTwo.value = (amountOne.value * rate).toFixed(2);
      });
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Jens, It did not work. Still negative values are taking

Comment: Hi Jens, Thanks It worked now, I figured out that i was passing the wrong value. Had to pass amountOne.value iinstead of currency_one

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in the .catch. However, that is a bad idea as you will be sending incorrect data to the server.

What you should do is, in calculate(), validate that the numbers are positive before calling fetch api.